# Getting ORA - 01653: Unable to extend table even in case of unlimited quota

Tags: database, oracle

I have a DB table where I need to populated around 16k rows. I have allocated unlimited quota to my user in the associated tablespace. Still, I am getting the error message: 'Error ORA-01653: unable to extend table VMSUSER.R2 by 128'.

```
SQL> select * from user_ts_quotas;

TABLESPACE_NAME                     BYTES  MAX_BYTES     BLOCKS MAX_BLOCKS DRO
------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---
USERS                          3.4278E+10         -1    4184360         -1 NO
```

Please let me know the cause of this issue and how to resolve it.

Comment: no free space in tablespace?

Comment: The tablespace size is still limited by the total size of the data file(s) - that's completely seperate from user quotas. You'll need to talk to your DBA.

Answer (score 3):

As many people suggested already, `ORA-01653` means your table space is running short of storage.

You(or a DBA) may add a new datafile to the table space and it should be OK.

```
ALTER TABLESPACE <tablespace name> ADD DATAFILE '/path/to/new.dbf' SIZE <XXX>M;
```

Additionally, it is possible to set the tablespace to autoextend as well. [Here are the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/dfiles003.htm).